# Kubernetes log when pod migrated

Tags: kubernetes

I'm using a couple different versions of kubernetes - 1.7, 1.8, and 1.9 - and I'd like to know what log message to look for to know when a pod has been migrated from one node to another.

Comment: While it may be wider than you were expecting, `kubectl get events --watch` will emit cluster events when such a thing happens; I believe running `kubectl --v=100 get events --watch` will show the exact `curl` commands required to achieve the same effect

Answer (score 0):

One very easy way is to use the API through proxy.

For example:

- Run kube proxy to use curl without authentication

> kubectl proxy

- List all events with a watch

> curl -s 127.0.0.1:8001/api/v1/watch/events

That will generate some json output, and you may use a grep command or [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) command to format this json output.

> curl -s 127.0.0.1:8001/api/v1/watch/events | jq